# How do I call a Jupyter Notebook function within a bash script?

Tags: python, bash, jupyter-notebook

If I have a Jupyter Notebook file that contains a function, how do I call that function from a bash script or Linux command prompt?
I can successfully use
ipython -c "%run test.ipynb"
to run the python code in test.ipynb, which I can use for cases where I don't need to send any arguments in.

But if I have a file named another_test.ipnyb with function called find_error(n) and I want to call find_error from a bash script (or Linux command prompt), sending the appropriate value for the input argument, how do I do that?

I know I can use
python -c "import another_test; another_test.find_error(${n})"
to call function find_error(n) in another_test.py.
But I prefer to use ipynb files in this case.

Comment: Possible [XY problem](https://xyproblem.info). If you want to use a Python function it is simplest to save it in a file with an appropriate shebang line  or run it with `python /path/to/file`.

Comment: You aren't telling us how you coded this function, and so it is hard to add specifics. (Always best to provide a minimal reproducible example. You can even link to actual notebooks as gists.) Are you familiar with using import in Python. Using additional modules, you can import the notebook and thus the function, see [here](https://discourse.jupyter.org/t/package-for-importing-jupyter-notebooks-as-modules/12923/2?u=fomightez).

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you can actually do this. I'm pretty sure those notebook files are just JSON. Maybe you can convert this notebook to python in your script, then call the resulting python script with your input.

Something like this

```
#!/bin/bash

# Convert the Jupyter notebook to a Python script
jupyter nbconvert --to script another_test.ipynb

# Rename the Python script
mv another_test.py another_test_script.py

# Call the Python function with the input argument
python -c "from another_test_script import find_error; print(find_error($1))"
```

Then call with `./myscript.sh "my error input"`.

Comment: I'll add that you can also use [jupytext](https://jupytext.readthedocs.io/en/latest/using-cli.html) to replace the `jupyter nbconvert` command. Jupytext is a nice tool to have in your toolbox for things like this. It will even automatically maintain `.ipynb` and `.py` versions of files, if you;d like. Using `importnb` as I point out though in my comment below the OP, would probably be more straightforward way to accomplish what your goal seems to be by combining the last steps in Psilly's answer with the use of importing the notebook function.